# How do I align the columns in CSS flexbox?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

I'm having two issues with the layout of my weather app

1. the white space around the bottom and right edges
2. I can't figure out how to align the weekdays with the column of 5 red boxes underneath it so they're both side my side

I'm taking a mobile first approach so you need to view it in the dev console using the phone screen sizes as I haven't added the media queries yet.

https://lettda.github.io/WeatherWiz/

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @PraveenKumar 1) This doesn't answer my question nor does it help in anyway 2) I clearly stated I wanted them side by side 3) In order to understand what I was looking at a visual was needed not my HTML and entire stylesheet

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required is that *we want to help*. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate any of the code needed to duplicate the problem. This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem with such questions. Without a [mcve] the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher, which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to *guess* at significant portions of what your problem might be.

Comment: @mayken Hands down the most helpful answer I've gotten! Thank you for putting into perspective and explaining why it was necessary. I realize this is code I've written and starred at for a while and I automatically understand where the pieces fit, but you all don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- On `.footer` set `bottom: -1px;` (it will stick it to the bottom)
- Add the class `.col-xs-6` to `#weekDay` (it will use half 12 column grid)
- Add the other `.col-xs-6` to `#weekly_forecast` (it will use the
  other half of the 12 column grid)
- Add `line-height: 140px;` to `h2` to align it vertically with the red `div`s.
- For bigger `width` viewports replicate same formula with `col-md-*`s

[image]